# Iterative if function

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, iteration

I am currently working on a python script which will take a string, convert it to a list, and then remove all of the vowels. It then prints out the final result as a string. However, the iterative function I am using is outputting every result, whether it is a vowel or not. I have tried reversing and only keeping the consonants, but to no avail. Below is the code I was using.

```
string = input("#: ")
new_list = []

for x in list(string):
    if [x.lower() == y for y in list("aeiou")]:
        global new_list
        new_list.append(x)

print(''.join(new_list))
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
if [x.lower() == y for y in list("aeiou")]
```

creates a list with five elements (each of which is `True` or `False`).
For instance, if `x` is `'e'`, it will create the list

```
[False, True, False, False, False]
```

If `x` is not a vowel, it will create the list

```
[False, False, False, False, False]
```

Any non-empty list is true, so the `if` condition is satisfied.

---

What you mean to ask is "does `x.lower()` equals `y` for any `y` in my list of vowels?", which is this:

```
if any(x.lower()==y for y in list("aeiou")):
```

or more succinctly:

```
if x.lower() in "aeiou":
```

If you want to check if a letter is *not* a vowel, it would be this:

```
if x.lower() not in "aeiou":
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what did you try to do there but this does it...

```
string = input("#: ")
print(''.join([x for x in string if x.lower() not in "aeiou"]))

#: Hello there!
Hll thr!
```

An even more efficient approach would be:

```
print(input("#: ").translate(str.maketrans("","","aeiou")))
```

Comment: Didn't realise it could be compacted by this much! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

one liner show off:

```
string = input("#: ")
print(''.join(filter(lambda x: x.lower() in 'aeiou', string)))
```

References

[1] https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter

[2] http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/lambda_functions.html

Answer (score 0):

First thing, a string is an iterator just like a list so no need to typecast a string to list.

```
s = "your_string_goes_here".lower()

s = s.replace('a', '')
s = s.replace('i', '')
s = s.replace('e', '')
s = s.replace('o', '')
s = s.replace('u', '')
print s
```

Comment: This scans the list 5 times.